# Multiply each component of vector by another vector (resulting in vector of length m*n)

Tags: r

Say I am making parts that come in three sizes, and each size has a certain tolerance:

```
target <- c(2, 4, 6)
tolerance <- c(0.95, 1.05)
```

What I'd like to end up with is an array that contains the limits of the tolerance for each target (i.e. target*0.95, target*1.05):

```
tol = (2*0.95, 2*1.05, 4*0.95, 4*1.05, 6*0.95, 6*1.05)
```

Here's a really ugly way of getting there, but I know there is a simple way to do this.

```
j<-1
tol<-NULL
for (i in target){
tol[j] <- i*tolerance[1]
tol[j+1] <- i*tolerance[2]
j<-j+2
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector `tol` can be calculated using `outer()` like this:

```
tol <- c(outer(tolerance,target))
#> tol
#[1] 1.9 2.1 3.8 4.2 5.7 6.3
```

Comment: while `outer` would be useful for other functions besides the product, it's worth noting that all it does is some extra checks and then `%*%` when the `FUN` argument is missing

Comment: ok, I don't disagree with any of that.. would you also like to talk about other tangentially related things to this problem? Let me clarify my statement - if you look at the source code, you'll see that all *this answer* does, is add fluff around `v1 %*% t(v2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using matrix product:

```
target <- c(2, 4, 6)
tolerance <- c(0.95, 1.05)
target %*% t(tolerance)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.9  2.1
[2,]  3.8  4.2
[3,]  5.7  6.3
```

Comment: This does provide what I want, however I wanted the result stored in a vector.  I'm passing the vector to `geom_vline` on a facet wrap plot where the data.frame that i will pass is `data.frame(tol, rep(as.factor(target), each=2))` such that each of the 3 subplots has the upper and lower tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer would have my preference, but this alternative might generalise better in some specific context (more than two vectors)

```
Reduce("*", expand.grid(list(tolerance, target)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for fun - using R's recycling:

```
rep(target, each = length(tolerance)) * tolerance
#[1] 1.9 2.1 3.8 4.2 5.7 6.3
```